# Jquery plugin getting DIV ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to pass to a plugin the ID of the DIV that's calling it.

A solution is calling it like this:

```
$('#mydiv').myplugin({
        myproperty : $('#mydiv').attr('id') 
    });
```

But I'd like to do something like this:

```
$('.myclass').myplugin({
    myproperty : $(this).attr('id') 
});
```

But "this" is not referring to myclass element. Is there a way to obtain myclass id dinamically?

Comment: Your second example should work, however I guess the problem is due to there being multiple elements with `.myclass`, and jQuery is returning the Id of the first one, which isn't the one you intend. A more precise selector would be required in this case.

Comment: Could you also post the code for `.myplugin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're attempting to use "$(this)" before your "myplugin" code even runs.  There's no direct way to do what you're doing, but this might work:

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
  $(this).myplugin({property: $(this).attr('id')});
});
```

Doing it that way, you allow jQuery to set up a function call to your "each" handler, with each element matching the selector individually. In each call to that function, `this` will refer to one of the elements. You then can call your plugin using properties of that element in the function call.